# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

[Moderator election #2](https://ai.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Artificial Intelligence has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new pro-tem moderator is:

[image: Mithical]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5426713998655488).

Answer (score 9):

Thank you all for putting your trust in me as a moderator! I look forward to helping with the upkeep of the site with my fancy new powers and making sure the site stays healthy alongside the existing team. :)

Comment: Great to have you join and help out! :)